# Linux: I need to create installer for my own application using shell script

Tags: linux, shell-script, software-installation

Linux: I need to create installer for my own application using shell script.

I need to distribute my application as installer without GUI and also not as rpm's or any other packages.

My application is java based. 
My installer should work in all Linux platforms (RHEL/ubuntu).

Please suggest me steps to do or any tool which is open source ???

Comment: Usually an interactive script (shell or otherwise) is used in such cases. Without further qualification of what your installer needs to do, it will be difficult for us to give a more specific answer. Meanwhile, take a look at `select` loops in Bash

Comment: you can also take a simple approach. How do you do in command line? save all the steps and they implement them in the script. $? eq 0 is a condition to evaluate if the output of the previous command executed properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got a solution

> [MakeSelf](http://megastep.org/makeself/)

This script bundles my application into a single file . later it extracts and executes a shell script.